# Loopback: Change the models folder structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I need change the models folder structure. According to the docs I can modify the json config file that by default is:

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models/**/*",
      "loopback/server/models/**/*",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },

  ...
}
```

I've been trying to change to:

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models/**/",
      "loopback/server/models/**/*",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },

  ...
}
```

But when I load the project, i get this error

```
Error: Model not found:
```

**How to change the models default directory for models??**

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve (which file(s) to include or exclude)? The only difference I can see from the above is `"loopback/common/models/**/*" -> "loopback/common/models/**/"`

Answer (score 0):

Just append your folder name.

```
{ 
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models/foldername",
      "loopback/server/models/foldername",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
}
```